# Conditional render label Color base on another field value

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements, predicate, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to render the label color base on another field value using test predicate or field predicate but I can not get it right.
All I want is that the label color on axis y (section) can change from black to red when its resilience value equal to 0.
I've made my code on online editor and I really appreciate if you can give me some help.

[vega-lite-condition-render-label-color](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAEyUAVhDYA7EABoQDCHABOCOJhSpQiJnAAmAeRyZ2siGlBq4sw+vVoQEYmRABfD0sNJt1kGIkQQY4K1QAbVBVKHM5ZwBGSgACAHE7dWDkgAk4YPpkgDJkgGUkADMtAE9FEABJezgADzQAZgAOSgAWAAYxAHZBoeH2pVsIGmE7KDg2hO9ouFiLRJ6UgFFZYho1OU1ZbUFkgEEoKBoHA6slBocW1A7uvuGX-tGQccmaadnUBIBOBYuJZxeToCQ5PKCAr8ZIABV2Mwg13qjXuj16A1eQ3enymshmbUBCkWy3i6FaKVy+RgyVhcLgbBwglmNzRbU6mOxOLGYS+PzQXX6QJioOcXSpVVoGSKyQAwiykLIaLJ3Gy7hynljubi+fjCageiKQSt0ABWKlQgpypC2WUAdTYagA1iqyPK5IY6BYUbdmpqudy3ryJvrfmIzcayWCQAA2DZNTDqWRZOFsQQhUGy9aJ2yaZL2vL0dQe+zeuS+9kPTnPIO60PfAm-BKxqNi9D9KlIABetsMbBUyQAsn51DRghACCVmBBtE3Kxrq1qg8GPnrGwaI23TSBOqUKtUTmcLnZMAv-UvAzqQ-ym4LWyTgdHnP8UtOmFA5Jg1EhYk6IMkAAqP4qm6tR+uiNbati9a3gaIAJJ4AC63ggJ+sjlDQ7i6IE3wAO4BLOuzOr8sgMBmXhKPAWFYG0PQ9EoSAMJgbATN2vw2Hy7FoN+oSoYISBVE4kSgMgLoBJgVQ4L8IBMLatSfmosjqAASkgXoqJshhoGIqHTGwXqqgE9ygJhcCCNp6B4hurIgJJ0nOAAjgwSrmNo5ikLUbksmgZEZoxTQ0OEoBkGoFw8WofFKNAwQcSA-bICqaARAxCT0ShqE1DhZkWc4oorEo9kyU6hnBLUSCBcFICheFqDlBOcA+GwiVgvVgiqIVNBQM64RtR1IACQYgjHMIZAxiy5SYLUg3mQAQkgqjCMpzgIBchg+UoM2CHC6mGdh-BmptSBDcY5TlKoU2GkdQ1yumToBOhXrtqASazs4viYAwCCUNZPzJAAvIDyQ9LUQQhDJtjaahYOhM4TACd1nidZgPmoH5giUXZbDpuYOABDlllrg2AqFVJMnOa5dB+DQnlKOUTrIJdICUD05RI2hd1qPj3y5VZ64k3ZZNOS5BxUx5tneTJJSKbZMWo6ACVIElkQMa0DFmurh2xgxsaHf0DH9Id7QMf8qXpWMSpkL8EQgAAxAAIus-StLGrS1LbABis3-B7HTux7-yze0YiIUonuzes7Ryv8-tmvbxw9KHdvrGI9v-Ak6zu3Ks327GXRJ7bs2xvbrRmh77vHKnCTG+7-RynK7T-Ga7tmmIEfHDHGWUaJtrOhJQtWeRtmfoI9189p0U0NxDx6QSBlgThJkgEgZChXwSYrRVtQE84EFeQPIAU6L7k07ZFVBb55GCHTDN+M4LNs8jqMgEOBlD8kKn83eXgeChQA)

in the case above, the fifth one <4. Hygiene & Cleaning> should be red instead of black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added another layer with text, in which your `text` of `section` field is displayed. In that the color config with condition will work properly. Below is the code and [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-glY1HxegBlCkAAvW2GNgqZIAWT86howQgBBKzAg2iblc11e1QeDn31jcNEbbZpAnVKFWqp3OlzsmAX-qXgd1IYFTaFrbJIOjzgBKWnTCgckwaiQsSdEGSAAVH9VTdWo-UxGsdVxetb0NEAEk8ABdbwQE-WRyhodxdECH4AHcAlnPZnT+WQGAzLwlHgLCsDaHoeiUJAGEwNhJm7P4bH5di0G-UJUMEJAqicSJQGQF0AkwKocD+EAmFtWpPzUWR1AAJSQL0VC2Qw0D6VCZjYL01QCB5QEwuBBG09ACQ3NkQEk6TnAARwYZVzG0cxSFqNzWTQMiM0YpoaHCUAyDUS4eLUPilGgYIOJAftkFVNAIgYhJ6JQ1CahwsyLOcMVViUeyZKdQzglqJBAuCkBQvC1BygnOAfDYRLwXqwRVEKmgoGdcI2o6kABIMdq0D6xqBqQIaTmEMgY1ZcpMFqQbzIAISQVRhGU5wEEuQwfKUJbBARdTDOw-gxH2ibzOMcpylUBajQuob5XTJ0+gCZocDUZxfEwBgEEoazfmSAAeZI+laHpkgAfmSAByWxDFh5JUDh0K4DsWHPEe8znsEJ0AnQr121AJNZ2+vw-oB9cgYAPmSMRaiCEIZIRrHAmCUJnDRuw2e80jyMESi7LYdNzBwAIcsstcG0FQqpJk5zXLoPwaE8pRyidZB7pASgenKNnPzxr7sp+XKrOpu85Yc9BFcOZWPNsvnnBKRTbJinycISpAksiBiIYUMQGLEc7YwY2NzoGBiBnO9oGIBVL0vGZUyD+CIQAAYgAEQ2AZWljVpanTgAxZaASLjpC6LgFlvaPpEKUYvlo2dp5QBSuxEzk4enrjONj6TOAQSDZC-lZbM9jLoe-T5bY0z1oxCLwuTn7hJY8LgZ5XldoAQZhuxD6JuTjbjLKNE21nQk+XnCTRNyum2a4Hmtn9JOiTmnu0zTal-L4lQw38ZwoTcs4ISZhG1j9SmgMmwgzBozDmLMjBsyZpzdA3N5CoRMvFCmCA0DGiUFlT+5lv6mniFbYqahSqCE8KfEAYkL44SKs4SKe00IvWNmubS0UaDcUeHpIkBkwI4UwUgMgaMKBJi2hVWoktnAQS8lfG2Lk7buVVrZCqQVfIC3VprPwzhdb606pgD2IAhwGXInAZIKkLbEi8B4FCQA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "usermeta": {"embedOptions": {"renderer": "svg"}},
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "section": "1. General Health & Safety",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": 31
      },
      {
        "section": "10. Environmental Accidents",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": 19
      },
      {
        "section": "2. Health - Process",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": 39
      },
      {
        "section": "3. Health - People",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": 47
      },
      {
        "section": "4. Hygiene & Cleaning",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": 0
      },
      {
        "section": "5. Health Care & Working Conditions",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": 25
      },
      {
        "section": "6. External Pollution & Extreme Weather Conditions",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": 16
      },
      {
        "section": "7. Hazardous Materials/Substances",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": 25
      },
      {
        "section": "8. Safety Accidents",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": 46
      },
      {
        "section": "9. Subcontractors Training",
        "Index": 38.40277777777778,
        "resilience": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": null}},
  "height": 300,
  "autosize": {"resize": true},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "cornerRadiusEnd": 2},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "resilience",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": null,
          "axis": {"grid": true},
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 100]}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "section",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {
            "grid": false,
            "domain": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labels": false,
            "labelAlign": "left",
            "labelBaseline": "middle",
            "labelPadding": -5,
            "labelOffset": 0,
            "labelColor2": {"expr": "datum.resilience < 230 ? 'red' : 'green'"},
            "labelColor": {
              "condition": {"test": "datum.resilience > 5", "value": "red"},
              "value": "green"
            },
            "title": null
          }
        },
        "tooltip": {
          "field": "resilience",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "format": ".0f"
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "resilience",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Score",
          "scale": {
            "domain": [0, 30, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 90, 100],
            "range": [
              "#DE7363",
              "#FB9F38",
              "#F9B821",
              "#FBE8C9",
              "#F5DA01",
              "#E2D91E",
              "#CBD641",
              "#B6D35F",
              "#A2D180",
              "#7CC895",
              "#52BEA9"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "section"},
        "color": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.resilience < 2", "value": "red"},
          "value": "green"
        },
        "x": {"datum": 0},
        "y": {"field": "section", "type": "ordinal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "red", "size": 3},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "max",
          "field": "Index",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": null,
          "format": ".0f",
          "title": "Module Resilience"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```